# Apache Axis2/Java is not updated since April 2012

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I was wondering to ask what think to the community about Apache Axis2/Java.
This library is not updated since April 2012, this looks to me as the product is abandoned.

I was also wondering to ask what should I think about all those software programs and products built up on Axis2.

Answer (score 2):

Product is not abandoned and there are some contributions, but they are too small.